# Refencing the node of a .props file in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I've been trying to reference the directory in a .props file, that way I could parse it and use it as a variable for a python project. The problem however is that the header of the file is being treated as the root of the program, and I haven't been able to reference the main root no matter what I've done. I've tried 'json.dumps()', 'root.iter()', 'root.findall()', and a slew of other options to try and get past the header, but everytime I try the result either generates an error, or nothing at all.
I'm guessing it's because I'm using a props file and while similar, these solutions are supposed to be for .xml files, but I haven't found anything that implies I should be dealing with .props files any differently.

In short. How can I take the information in the MainRoot node below, and, in a separate python program, parse it and make it into a variable? Said props file is below.

```xml
    <!--YouFoundMe.props-->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <MainRoot>..\..\..\YouFoundMe</MainRoot>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Project>
```

This may not be important, but if it helps, I'll also post a python file containing some of the failed methods I tried below:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import json


    tree = ET.parse('YouFoundMe\YouFoundMe.props')
    root = tree.getroot()
    FIND_ME_DIR = json.dumps(root.attrib)
    boobop = json.dumps(root.tag)
    print(FIND_ME_DIR)

    for child in root:
        print(child.tag) 
        print(child.attrib)

    for MainRoot in root.iter('Project'):
        print(MainRoot.attrib)
    for MainRoot in root.iter('PropertyGroup'):
        print(MainRoot.attrib)
    for MainRoot in root.iter('MainRoot'):
        print(MainRoot.attrib)

    for child in root.iter('MainRoot'):
        print("Aything? Please?")

    for PROP in root.findall('PropertyGroup'):
        result = PROP.find('MainRoot').text
        print(result)

    for MainRoot in root.findall('Project'):
        print("Text")
    for MainRoot in root.findall('PropertyGroup'):
        print("Text")
    for MainRoot in root.findall('MainRoot'):
        print("Text")

    element = root.find('Project')
    if not element:  # careful!
        print("element not found, or element has no subelements")
    if element is None:
        print("element not found")

    test = str(root.get("Project"))
    print(test) 
    test = str(root.get("PropertyGroup"))
    print(test) 
    test = str(root.get("MainRoot"))
    print(test)  

    print(tree)
    print(root)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that your XML has *default namespace* declared at the root element level:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
```

Note that descendant elements without prefix, including `MainRoot`, inherit this default namespace implicitly. You can define a prefix that references the above default namespace and then use that prefix to find `MainRoot`, for example:

```
ns = { 'd': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' }
main_root = root.find('.//d:MainRoot', namespaces=ns)
print(main_root.text)
```